# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR max number of clients reached

Tags: java, redis

I am trying to connect the redis database using jedis-client in the web application but after some day the application throwing an exception as below:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR max number of clients reached
```

I tried to figure out is it due to the redis not able to handle the connection or may be i have not close the redis connection.

```
//code snippet to connect redis
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
jedis.connect();
```

I have not closed the connection as I was thinking the connection will get close by redis-server as it is idle.
May be this will be cause.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Can you improve the wording of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be opening a connection every time you would like to query your redis server. After a while you get too many clients connected and the server just cannot accept new connections.

There are several options:

**Disconnect idle clients server side**

If you want your redis server to disconnect idle clients, you should look into your redis configuration:
    # Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)
    timeout 0

See the [reference redis conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf).
You probably have this value set at 0. Changing it and restarting you redis server should solve your issue.

**Close the connection client side**

Just call

```
jedis.quit();
```

This will tell both your server and client to close the connection. If there is no need to maintain a connection, it's more elegant.

**Use a Connection pool**

If you have several clients/threads in your redis application you should use the connection pool in Jedis client. It should already be included in you dependency.

It will maintain/recreate connections when needed.
You query the pool when you need the connection and give it back to it when you are done querying (exactly like a jdbc pool).

Here is the [basic example](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#basic-usage-example) from their documentation.

Comment: I have already done the timeout 0 configuration at the redis.conf file and was in the impression that the above error will be handle but still the issue came.I will try the second approach.But still I can't get it why the timeout 0 didn't work.Any idea?

Comment: you're supposed to set a timeout value in seconds and not 0. For example 5. This means that every client idle for more than 5 seconds will be deconnected. Setting it to 0 disables the timeouts.